# How to use Safeargs with multiple navGraphs

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-navigation, android-safe-args

I am creating an app for a school assignment where I need to use 2 activities, which both have a navGraph with multiple fragments.

I know how to pass data between the fragments, but I need to pass data from the userActivity to the mainActivity using safeArgs.

I need to pass the userId from the userFragment to the mainFragment

I haven't been able to find any information on this, could someone help me out?

[user navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJHQg.png)

[main navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY2dS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the args from `UserFragment` to `MainActivity` first, then extract the args inside your `MainFragment` using `MainFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireActivity().intent.extras)`. For details check out this simple repository I just created that implements your requirements.

https://github.com/phamtdat/MultipleNavGraphDemo